# Overwriting files in Node server

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, express

So I have a server that temporarily saved the files in it's memory, before I upload them to the database. Here's my code:

```
uploadImage(file, uid, res) {
    var fs = require('fs');
    mongoose.connect(config.db, {useNewUrlParser: true},).catch(e => console.log(e));
    var conn = mongoose.connection;
    Grid.mongo = mongoose.mongo;
    const gfs = Grid(conn.db);
    const writeStream = gfs.createWriteStream({
        filename: file.filename,
    });
    fs.createReadStream(file.path).pipe(writeStream);
    writeStream.on('close', file => {
        const {_id} = file;
        return Account.findByIdAndUpdate(uid, {'employer.logo': _id}).then(() => res.redirect('/employer')).catch(e => console.log(e));
    });
},
```

I am trying to optimize the images before uploading them to the database, like this:

```
async uploadImage(file, uid, res) {
    const imagemin = require('imagemin');
    const imageminJpegtran = require('imagemin-jpegtran');
    const imageminPngquant = require('imagemin-pngquant');
    console.log(1);
    // const newFilePath = `${file.path}optimized`;
    const newFile = await imagemin([file.path], file.path, {
        plugins: [
            imageminJpegtran(),
            imageminPngquant({quality: '65-80'})
        ]
    });
    // newFile.path = newFilePath;
    console.log(2);
    console.log(file);
    console.log(newFile);
    var fs = require('fs');
    await mongoose.connect(config.db, {useNewUrlParser: true},).catch(e => console.log(e));
    var conn = mongoose.connection;
    Grid.mongo = mongoose.mongo;
    const gfs = Grid(conn.db);
    const writeStream = gfs.createWriteStream({
        filename: newFile.filename,
    });
    fs.createReadStream(newFile.path).pipe(writeStream);
    writeStream.on('close', file => {
        const {_id} = file;
        return Account.findByIdAndUpdate(uid, {'employer.logo': _id}).then(() => res.redirect('/employer')).catch(e => console.log(e));
    });
},
```

But this tells me `EEXIST: file already exists, mkdir '/home/alex/Documents/Projects/ontario-job-portal/public/images/logos/b80872b65d18d09bb498abcabe2f3f94'`, which is true. I'm trying to overwrite the previous image.

How can I make it overwrite the file though?

Creating a new file results in a permission denied error.

Edit. ***IMPORTANT***

Turns out, that the object returned by the imagemin function is a little different from the previous one. Here's my working code:

```
async uploadImage(file, uid, res) {
    const imagemin = require('imagemin');
    const imageminJpegtran = require('imagemin-jpegtran');
    const imageminPngquant = require('imagemin-pngquant');
    console.log(1);
    const path = require("path");
    const newFilePath = path.dirname(file.path);
    const newFile = await imagemin([file.path], path.dirname(file.path), {
        plugins: [
            imageminJpegtran(),
            imageminPngquant({quality: '65-80'})
        ]
    });
    newFile.path = newFilePath;
    newFile.filename = newFile[0].path.replace(/public\/images\/logos\//, '');
    console.log(newFile.filename);
    var fs = require('fs');
    await mongoose.connect(config.db, {useNewUrlParser: true},).catch(e => console.log(e));
    var conn = mongoose.connection;
    Grid.mongo = mongoose.mongo;
    const gfs = Grid(conn.db);
    console.log(2);
    const writeStream = gfs.createWriteStream({
        filename: newFile[0].filename,
    });
    console.log(3);
    fs.createReadStream(newFile[0].path).pipe(writeStream);
    console.log(4);
    writeStream.on('close', file => {
        console.log(5);
        const {_id} = file;
        return Account.findByIdAndUpdate(uid, {'employer.logo': _id}).then(() => res.redirect('/employer')).catch(e => console.log(e));
    });
},
```

Comment: Not sure on how to overwrite, but is it very costly to remove the file and then creating it again?

Comment: Creating a new file results in a permission denied error. But if you could provide an example I'd be happy to test it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are providing the path of an existing file to [imagemin](https://github.com/imagemin/imagemin#output) where a directory is required.  To extract the directory from the path, use `path.dirname(file.path)`:

```
const path = require("path");
const newFile = await imagemin([file.path], path.dirname(file.path), {
    ...
```

Note that this won't overwrite the existing file.  It doesn't appear that imagemin supports that directly.  You could do it yourself manually using `fs` if you wanted, but I'm not sure why you would.  It seems like you are interested in using these as temporary files.  You may want to add some code to delete the files after they have been written to mongo.

Comment: This caused the server to respond with `Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read` Any idea how to fix it?